# Is it possible to use neo4j-reco with neo4j 1.9?

Tags: neo4j, recommendation-engine, graphaware

The title says pretty much all. I'm trying to use `neo4j-reco` by `GraphAware` on top of `neo4j-1.9`. However, I don't know if it is possible at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the neo4j-reco has been built starting from Neo4j 2.1.5, see here : 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphaware.neo4j/recommendation-engine

And some methods use the Neo4j 2.0+ API.

In the meantime, we can just recommend you to upgrade to Neo4j 2.2

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately, I can't upgrade Neo4j because I'm working on a legacy project on which I don't have any control. So, the version of the recommendation engine match the same version of Neo4j?

Comment: yes the 3 first numbers are the neo4j version, the last 3 the recommendation engine version